# eclipse on macOS 10 doesn't launch

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, launch, macos-sierra

I downloaded and installed eclipse for macOS 10.

However, when I want to launch it, I keep getting the following error message:

```
**Eclipse quit unexpectedly.**

Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.
```

On this website:

```
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini
```

I was told to change the content of the eclipse.ini file. As demanded, I added the following two lines to the file (before the "vmargs" line):
    -vm
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

But, of course, it still doesn't work. 
Any ideas what's going wrong here?

UPDATE: HERE ARE THE CRASH LOGS:

```
Process:               eclipse [4311]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/*/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:            org.eclipse.platform.ide
Version:               4.4.0 (4.4.0.I20140606-1215)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           eclipse [4311]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-12-20 23:25:52.945 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.1 (16B2555)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        xxx

Sleep/Wake UUID:       xxx

Time Awake Since Boot: 17000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       7100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003c
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x3c:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100004000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /var/folders/*/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5b4ab54 CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName + 36
1   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x000000010000306b findSymbol + 66
2   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x00000001000017f6 original_main + 1572
3   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x0000000100001eb5 main + 1230
4   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x0000000100001090 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeacdf4e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeadc7622 _pthread_wqthread + 1023
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeadc7211 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeacdf4e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeadc77b5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeadc7211 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeacdf4e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeadc77b5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeadc7211 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000608000020320  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x6974696e49746573  rdx: 0x0000000000000006
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000608000020320  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff960  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff530
   r8: 0x736772416c616974   r9: 0x0000000000000600  r10: 0x0000000000000002  r11: 0x00007fffd5b4ab30
  r12: 0x00000001000043f8  r13: 0x00006080000a0000  r14: 0x0000608000020320  r15: 0x34615d5cea670073
  rip: 0x00007fffd5b4ab54  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x000000000000003c

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

Comment: Eh... Could you please post the **crash logs and stuff**?

Comment: I don't have any crash logs ... I just double clicked on the eclipse button and got the error message

Comment: click the "Report" button. Then, some logs will be displayed, under the text entry asking for a message about reproducing. Copy them **all** here.

Comment: You are using a fairly old version of Eclipse (4.4). The current Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) works fine for me on macOS 10.12

Comment: I just downloaded eclipse a couple of days ago ... I downloaded the newest version I could get ... let me check again